# Is $x^{100} - x^2 + 1$ separable in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, separable-extension

My approach: $f'(X) = 100x^{99} - 2x = 0x^{99} - 0x = 0$ since in $\mathbb{F}_2$. So the $\gcd(f,f') = f > 1$, thus not separable.

On the other hand, $f(0) \neq 0 \neq f(1)$, <s>so irreducible. But irreducible, implies separable in a finite field</s>, so no roots.

So is $f$ actuallly separable or not? What am I missing here?

Comment: The fact that $f(0)\neq0\neq f(1)$ means this polynomial has no roots; it does not mean that it is irreducible. For example maybe it factors as the product of two irreducible degree 50 polynomials, or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your polynomial has no root does NOT imply that it is irreducible (this kind of argument works only for polynomials of degree $2$ or $3$. Think of $(x^2+1)^2\in\mathbb{R}[x])$.

(And your polynomial is indeed NOT separable, by the way .)

Comment: Thanks @GreginGre! Ah I totally agree with the first part. I will edit my post. Could you please elaborate the latter? Isn't separable iff $gcd(f, f') = 1$, but here the gcd is not a constant?

Comment: This polynomial is not separable. It is the square of a separable polynomial, $x^{50}+x+1$.

Comment: Doing the simple math, I agree!

Comment: sorry, it's a typo, i forgot the word "NOT" ...